# Installing ubuntu 20.04 server: how to delete a partition?

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04 server. While in the «Storage configuration» step, among the «available devices» I want to delete a partition.
That partition is labelled as such: `partition 7 existing, already formatted as ext4, not mounted`.

When I press the space bar on that partition, I get a window where I have to choose between `close`, `Edit`, `Delete *`.

When I choose delete I get the following message: `Cannot delete a single partition from  device that already has partitions`.

When I press the `Edit` option, I have a Format option from where I can choose the file system I want to format the partition with `ext4`, `xfs`, `btrfs`, `swap`. None of those options allow me to format.
Below are some pictures for illustration purpose.

How to delete that partition? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a [subiquity bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1868249) about this, and it looks like the installer doesn't support deleting partitions.

Your options are to erase entire disk and create partitions from scratch, or switch to a different console (Alt+F2) and use a different partitioning tool (`parted`, `cfdisk`).

Comment: I already tried the cfdisk option, but was not able to format. How the subiquity bug report helps?